# How can I check if this is last member of std::list?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a list like below

```
typedef std::list<std::string> SegmentValue;
```

then in a iteration I need check if this is last iteration.

```
     for(Field::SegmentValue::const_iterator it = m_segmentValue.begin();It != 
           m_segmentValue.end();It++){
              if((segIt + 1) == m_segmentValue.end())//last iteration
              ...
        }
```

but I get error in compile that:

```
 error C2678: binary '+' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::list<_Ty>::_Const_iterator<_Secure_validation>'
```

how I can check if this is last itration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use binary `+` and `-` operators with `std::list` iterators. `std::list` iterators are *bidirectional* iterators, but they are not *random access* iterators, meaning that you can't shift them by an arbitrary constant value.

Use unary `++` and `--` instead

```
Field::SegmentValue::const_iterator it_last = m_segmentValue.end();
--it_last;
```

Now `it_last` is the last element iterator. Just make sure it remains valid. If you are not making any iterator-invalidating modifications to your container, you can pre-compute `it_last` and use it in the cycle. Otherwise, you'll have to re-compute it as necessary.

In fact, in generic algorithms it is always a good idea to prefer using `--` and `++` with iterators whenever possible (instead of binary `+ 1` and `- 1`), since it reduces your algorithm's requirements: binary `+` and `-` require *random access* iterators, while `++` and `--` work with *bidirectional* ones.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next):

```
if (std::next(segIt) == m_segmentValue.end()) ...
```

If you're using C++03, you can easily write `next` yourself:

```
template<typename T> T next(T it, typename std::iterator_traits<T>::difference_type n = 1) {
    std::advance(it, n);
    return it;
}
```

Comment: I'd rather precompute it before the loop using `std::prev` on `end()`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
Field::SegmentValue::const_iterator last = m_segmentValue.end()
--last;

for(Field::SegmentValue::const_iterator it = m_segmentValue.begin();
    It != m_segmentValue.end();
    It++) {

        if(It == last) {
            // last iteration
        }     
    }
```

You can only do arithmetic with Random Access Iterators. `std::list`'s iterators are Bidirectional.

See [**here**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) for what you can and cannot do with iterators of various categories.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Field::SegmentValue::const_iterator next = it; ++next;
// or in C++11:
// Field::SegmentValue::const_iterator next = std::next( it );
if( next == m_segmentValue.end()) //last iteration
```

List iterators are `Bidirectional`, not `RandomAccess` so they don't support `operator+`.

Answer (score 0):

std::list iterator are not random access, they are bidirectional. The operator+ is not supported. You need to use std::vector to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if ( &*it == &*(m_segmentValue.rbegin()))
```

i.e, comparing the addresses of the segments.